# Data type somehow gets converted when appended to a list

Tags: python, binary, ascii

I am trying to convert text to binary using ASCII encoding, and then decode the binary back to text as proof of concept for a larger project. The following code works well and does what it is supposed to do:

```
bytes = []

input_data = "Hello"

for b in input_data:
    new_byte = bin(int.from_bytes(b.encode('ascii'), 'big'))
    bytes.append(new_byte)

for x in bytes:
    print(x)

for byte in bytes:
    byte_int = int(byte, 2)
    output_data = str(byte_int.to_bytes(byte_int, 'big').decode('ascii'))
    print(output_data)
```

However, as soon as I try to append the given value of `output_data` to a list within the for loop, the strings become converted to HEX for some odd reason.

```
bytes = []
output_list = []

input_data = "Hello"

for b in input_data:
    new_byte = bin(int.from_bytes(b.encode('ascii'), 'big'))
    bytes.append(new_byte)

for x in bytes:
    print(x)

for byte in bytes:
    byte_int = int(byte, 2)
    output_data = str(byte_int.to_bytes(byte_int, 'big').decode('ascii'))
    print(output_data)
    output_list.append(output_data)

print(output_list)
```

With the output:

```
0b1001000
0b1100101
0b1101100
0b1101100
0b1101111
H
e
l
l
o
['\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00H', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00e', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00l', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00l', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00o']
```

I have no idea why this happens, is there any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misused the [int.to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method. As the doc states,

> int.to_bytes(length, byteorder, *, signed=False)
>
> Return an array of
> bytes representing an integer. [...]
>
> The integer is represented using
> length bytes.

You used `byte_int.to_bytes(byte_int, 'big')`, so you convert for example the integer 72 into a byte string of length 72, which gives you 71 null bytes before the one representing your value.

You want a single byte, so use

```
output_data = str(byte_int.to_bytes(1, 'big').decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Ah, silly mistake, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

When you are printing the `list` object itself and not its content, the actual content doesn't get printed in a representation way. That is why you see HEX values.

To achieve what you want, simply unpack the list:

```
print(*output_data)
```

Or this way:

```
for item in output_list:
    print(item, end=' ')
```